# Excel Color a cell if it is an row outlier

Tags: excel, format, vba

I want to change the color of a cell if it is an outlier in its row, and apply this to all cells in the spreadsheet. Defining an outlier as a value two standard deviations away from the mean (of the row). How could I do this?

Sample Data

[image: Sample]

Formula I have so far:

```
=$C$9>(N9+2*$O$9)
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to change the color of a cell if it is an outlier? or are you also asking how to calculate the outlier? If you require to change the color of the cell, the best way would be using conditional formatting.

Comment: Yes, change the color. I tried conditional formatting but "painting" the formula down the column doesn't seem to dynamically change the conditional formatting formula. I have separate cells for each row with the mean and stdev so the calculation is easy just dynamically coloring the cells is stumping me...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your conditional formatting? Did you apply the conditional formatting to a range ?

Comment: No, just one cell at the moment.

Comment: Is Row 9 the first row in the image?

Comment: Yes, I hid all rows that don't have data in them.

Comment: @Marcus The original formula you were using in you conditional formatting was locked. and would not allow cells addresses to update as the formatting was applied through the selected range.  Also you were only looking at the case where it was greater than two standard deviations.  you needed to consider less than two standard deviations as well.  At least based on your Q write up.

Comment: Yeah, I was just keeping it simple. There is some more complicated logic I want to implement too once I got the conditional formatting down. Thanks by the way very good answer!

Comment: I also noticed you are using STDDEV.p instead of STDDEV.s  I dont know which one you want to be using, but I did note they gave different values.  Just thought I would give a heads up on that in case you were not aware.

Comment: Actually yeah forgot about that, stdev in R is the stdev.s value. Been a while since I checked good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your formula for you conditional formatting:

```
=OR(C9>($N9+2*$O9),C9<($N9-2*$O9))
```

Now you will need to properly apply it to the entire range.  In order to do this, follow these steps:

1. Select the top left corner of your data and drag to the bottom right corner.  This should leave the area in a grey zone with the top left cell being a white background and also known as the active cell.

[image: Selecting Range]

2. Select conditional formatting from the ribbon and use the formula to determine as you have in your screen shot.
3. Enter the formula above in the formula bar.  Note has the row numbers are not locked in all cases and only the column are locked with $ for column N and O.  The formula will adjust itself as it moves through the selected range and away from the active cell which you enter the formula on.
4. Set up any formatting you want applied when the value of a cell is more than 2 std away from the mean.

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]